# Record JSON array to text file with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Please be kind with your answers, I am really new to JSON and PHP and any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

So far I have created a php file which using the following code

```
$data = print_r($_POST, TRUE); 
file_put_contents('api3.txt', $data);
```

which captured a POST message and saved it to the file api3.txt. From what I understand JSON arrays are not sent in POST messages, meaning that I should use something like

```
$jsonString = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input");
$myFile = "01010.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile,$jsonString);
```

This code is based on looking at other similar SO questions however I'm having some problems and not receiving any saved content to that text file. The only thing I know about the JSON data coming in is that it is in an array and it is being sent to my php script (not read from a file or page).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

The following code produced a textfile of work.txt that contained `1`

```
<?php
header('realtimeapi_code: #####');
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = print_r($jsonString);
file_put_contents('work.txt',$data);
?>
```

The first line in the header is required for authentication.

Comment: what does `print_r($jsonString);` produce?

Comment: I suppose this was the other part of my question. Given that the php script is located on my hosting space and receives JSON data anytime someone enters a promotion, how would `print_r($jsonString);` work. Where would that print to? The php file?

Comment: Create another PHP file and post JSON from it to your host code and then it will get that response, that way you can code for the real thing

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of json_encode(), json_decode() and urlencode().

POST

```
// encode PHP array to JSON
$data = json_encode(array("something"=>array("key"=>"val")));
// urlencode it for sending via POST
$data = urlencode($data);
```

RECEIVE

```
$dataEncodedJSON = $_POST['yourDataField'];
$data = json_decode( urldecode( $dataEncodedJSON), true);
var_dump($data, true);
```

You might get away with a one-liner:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.website.com/'), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I should have included the fact that I am not creating the JSON array, it is being pushed to my site from an API. Unfortunately the API has literally no documentation other than indicating "our server will send a JSON array to your callback URL for parsing".

Does this change your answer?

Comment: No, that doesn't change my answer. It's just easier for you, because you don't have to deal with sending JSON via AJAX or POST from your own site. Basically, you need to know the $_POST array key, the API sends it's data or just use the stream input method, like you already do, then decode the JSON. You might test, if you need to urldecode the incoming data first. That depends on how the API sends the data.